# Is there a list of gear I can receive from winning a battleground (lvl 20)

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm a F2P (free to play) player in WoW, meaning I'm stuck at level 20, unable to use such things as mailboxes or the auction house. That means that if I want gear, I have to work for it (I know, working in a game - ah, Blizzard). At least until the legion patch.

That patch introduced gear that you can obtain when winning a random battleground. You get a crate containing a mark of honor and a random piece of gear suited to your class.

My question is, where can I find a list of gear that can be obtained? I have so far been unable to find any such list. The closest I've gotten is [this search on WoWhead](http://www.wowhead.com/items/armor/leather/name:Rookie's). I know that some of those items, including everything that's listed as level 43 (which is in reality level 25) are obtainable, because I have them on various characters. I'm not so sure about the items listed as level 62, as I have not seen them yet.

**Question:** Is there a list of gear obtainable by winning BGs for a level 20 player?

Note: I'm doing this primarily to see if the horde's long wait for headgear wearable by level 20 is over. All we get is the Lucky Fishing Hat, which takes about 6 months to grind, and a lot of luck. No guilds for F2P, meaning no guild heirlooms, like headgear.

Comment: You cold look up the crate on wowhead. if you filter the containing results you should get your list.

Comment: That was my first thought. It doesn't list the contents. http://www.wowhead.com/item=135539/crate-of-battlefield-goods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no viable list of items, but you can set a workaround filter on WoWHead using the data we already know:

- Added in patch 7.0.3
- ILvl 43, 62
- From a bit of looking we can narrow down the item ids to be between 134600 and 134700
- **Search result:** [clicky](http://www.wowhead.com/items/min-level:43/max-level:62/group-by:slot?filter=82:151:151;2:5:1;70003:134700:134600)

This gives you the following:

- **Cloth**: Auxiliary's ...
- **Leather**: Rookie's ...
- **Mail**: Greenhorn's ...
- **Plate**: Front-Line ...
- **Everything else** (rings, trinkets, weapons/off-hand items): Recruit's ...

Note: There is no Neck listed, so this might not be added as reward. All the other item slots are available.

Comment: Thanks. Still no confirmation that starters can get the headgear, but it's a place to start. Thanks for your time! Off-topic question, what is iLvl?

Comment: @ThomasMyron that's a shortcut for Item Level. And if you follow the link you can see a set of head gear as well. Only neck gear is missing.